# How to make code reviews when using git-tfs bridge?

Tags: git, tfs, git-tfs

In our team it is allowed to make commits only after code review is done.

So quite often colleagues send you a code review request. How are you going to see it available in Visual Studio while connected to local repository instead of Team Server?

Comment: feature request for git-tfs https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues/913

Answer (score 1):

Keep a second Visual Studio running and connected to TFS version control, and flip between them.

Answer (score -2):

The most efficient is perhaps to ask someone to do the review on your computer with you.

If that's not possible, the only solution that I see is to squash all the commits and to do a shelve from the remaining commit and after create a code review from this shelve set. Not a perfect solution...

The better solution, like even Microsoft advise, is to migrate to tfs(git) ;-)

Comment: Microsoft has never stated that their general advice is to migrate to Git.